# Получить один столбец из данных pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Я беру DataFrame и разбиваю столбец на два `datetime = data['tr_datetime'].str.split(' ')`

Получаю данные следующего вида:

```
0          [0, 10:23:26]
1          [1, 10:19:29]
2          [1, 10:20:56]
3          [1, 10:39:54]
4          [2, 15:33:42]
              ...       
99995    [152, 04:43:53]
99996    [152, 04:45:24]
99997    [153, 00:00:00]
99998    [153, 00:00:00]
99999    [155, 00:00:00]
Name: tr_datetime, Length: 100000, dtype: object
```

Как достать только первое значение из скобок? То есть 0,1,2,3 и тд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

наверняка способов много, например, такой тоже работает:

```
datetime = data['tr_datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам еще несколько векторизированных вариантов:

### Вариант 1:

```
df["num"] = df["tr_datetime"].str.split(n=1).str[0]
```

### Вариант 2:

```
df["num"] = df["tr_datetime"].str.extract(r"^(\d+)")
```